# Stackoverflow exception throws when getting property

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to store a list in a session object.

My Fruit basket class has an apples property which sets the session variable:

```
    public List<Apples> Apples
    {
        get { return HttpContext.Current.Session["Apples"] != null ? (List<Apples>)HttpContext.Current.Session["Apples"] :new List<Apples> {}; }
        set { HttpContext.Current.Session["Apples"] = value; }
    }
```

I assign a value like so:

```
FruitBasket.apples = db.Apples.tolist();
```

This works fine if the apples list has contents.
I get a stack overflow exception when retrieving fruitbasket.apples if the apples list is empty

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please show us the actual code you're using? The problem lies in the *details*, most likely a typo. It's difficult to give you an answer when it's clear we're not looking at the exact code being run. Your code: `FruitBasket.apples = db.Apples.tolist();` Firstly won't compile (since `tolist` is not a method assuming you haven't written your own `tolist` method - in which case, it would be useful to look at that), and secondly, would not be calling the method you've shown above.

Answer (score 1):

Your property name has the same type name with your list

```
public List<Apples> Apples
```

Try using a different name

```
public List<Apple> Apples
```

Comment: good spotting. I've just changed the property name. I'm still experiencing the stack overflow.

Comment: @JohnnyGrimes Post the new property here, did you also change the getter of the property?

Comment: Instad of changing the name of the list I've changed the name of the property so I dont think there is anything to change in the getter.

Comment: Wrong naming would not result in SO anyways.

Comment: @JohnnyGrimes can u show how to call this property?

Comment: @User2012384 (new FruitBasket).apples

Comment: @JohnnyGrimes The code won't compile, do you mean new FruitBasket().Apples? Try modify this fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/K6H40w to reproduce the problem

Comment: @User2012384 I have edited the fiddle, it's working as expected but is the same as the code in my application.

Would it make any difference that I'm calling new FruitBox from within the FruitBox class?

Comment: It doesn't make a difference, you have to check the call stack then